# Programatically get Windows Taskbar Info: AutoHidden State, Taskbar Coordinates, which Screen Edge it's on and Taskbar Thickness

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, taskbar

It took me a while to find this answer, so I thought I'd share it here as Q&A.

I wanted a way for my Visual Basic program program to retrieve the following info:

1. The location of Taskbar's top, bottom, left and right edges. Bottom
   and Top represents the y values of any point on those edges and top
   and left represents x values of any points on those edges.
2. The screen edge on which it resides: bottom, top, left or right screen
   edge
3. Autohidden State of Windows Taskbar
4. Thickness of Taskbar (remember that thickness will vary based on DPI and screen edge position where left and right edges may result in thicker    taskbars than the top and bottom ones).

Answer (score 1):

This code is written by me but based on the information I gleamed from [this post on CodeGuru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?443996-SHAppBarMessage). I would like to thank Visual Vincent whose suggested corrections in the comment section made it possible to run this code in x64.

Prep: Shared constants, variables and functions:

```
Const ABS_AUTOHIDE As Int32 = 1
Const ABS_ONTOP As Int32 = 2
Const ABM_NEW As Int32 = 0
Const ABM_REMOVE As Int32 = 1
Const ABM_QUERYPOS As Int32 = 2
Const ABM_SETPOS As Int32 = 3
Const ABM_GETSTATE As Int32 = 4
Const ABM_GETTASKBARPOS As Int32 = 5
Const ABM_ACTIVATE As Int32 = 6
Const ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAR As Int32 = 7
Const ABM_SETAUTOHIDEBAR As Int32 = 8
Const ABM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED As Int32 = 9

Const TB_POS_BOTTOM As Integer = 1
Const TB_POS_TOP As Integer = 2
Const TB_POS_LEFT As Integer = 3
Const TB_POS_RIGHT As Integer = 4

Private Declare Function apiSHAppBarMessage Lib "shell32" Alias "SHAppBarMessage" (ByVal dwMessage As UInt32, ByRef pData As APPBARDATA) As UIntPtr

Private Structure RECT
    Public rLeft, rTop, rRight, rBottom As Int32
End Structure

Private Structure APPBARDATA
    Public cbSize As UInt32, hwnd As IntPtr, uCallbackMessage, uEdge As UInt32, rc As RECT, lParam As IntPtr
End Structure

Dim ABD As New APPBARDATA
Dim Autohide_State As Int32
Dim taskbar_left, taskbar_right, taskbar_top, taskbar_bottom, taskbar_edge, taskbar_thickness As Integer
```

Part 1 & 2: The Sub below can be used to find the location of the taskbar's top, bottom, left and right edges AND the screen edge on which it resides.

```
    Private Sub GetTaskBarEdge_and_Coordinates()
    apiSHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ABD)
    taskbar_left = ABD.rc.rLeft
    taskbar_right = ABD.rc.rRight
    taskbar_top = ABD.rc.rTop
    taskbar_bottom = ABD.rc.rBottom

    'Figure out if it's located on the buttom, top, left or right edge of screen 
    If (taskbar_left < 5) And (taskbar_top > 5) Then
        taskbar_edge = TB_POS_BOTTOM
    ElseIf (taskbar_left < 5) And (taskbar_top < 5) And (taskbar_right > taskbar_bottom) Then
        taskbar_edge = TB_POS_TOP
    ElseIf (taskbar_left < 5) And (taskbar_top < 5) And (taskbar_right < taskbar_bottom) Then
        taskbar_edge = TB_POS_LEFT
    ElseIf (taskbar_left > 5) And (taskbar_top < 5) Then
        taskbar_edge = TB_POS_RIGHT
    Else
        MsgBox("Something went wrong while I was trying to find the taskbar edge. Please contact the develloper. Defaulting Edge to bottom.")
        taskbar_edge = TB_POS_BOTTOM
    End If
End Sub
```

Part 3: The Function Below will get you a integer value for the Autohidden state.

```
0 Means AH is off, Always on top is off.  
1 means AH is on and Always on Top is off. 
2 means AH is off and AoT is on. 
3 means AH and AoT are on.
```

Note the constants I setup in part 1: ABS_AUTOHIDE = 1 , ABS_ONTOP = 2.

```
Private Function GetTaskBarAHState() As Integer
    Return CInt(apiSHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE, Nothing))
End Function
```

Part 4: Taskbar thickness can be calculated from taskbar_bottom - taskbar_top OR taskbar_right - taskbar_left (depending on which edge the taskbar is).

```
Private Sub GetTaskBar_Thickness()

    GetTaskBarEdge_and_Coordinates()

    Select Case taskbar_edge
        Case TB_POS_BOTTOM
            taskbar_thickness = Math.Abs(taskbar_bottom - taskbar_top)
        Case TB_POS_TOP
            taskbar_thickness = Math.Abs(taskbar_bottom - taskbar_top)
        Case Case TB_POS_LEFT
            taskbar_thickness = Math.Abs(taskbar_right - taskbar_left)
        Case TB_POS_RIGHT
            taskbar_thickness = Math.Abs(taskbar_right - taskbar_left)
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Something went wrong while I tried to find Taskbar thickness. Please contact the develloper. Default to taskbar thickness of 39 [4]")
            taskbar_thickness = 39
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, but the fields in the `APPBARDATA` structure are not of the correct type. `cbSize` should be `UInt32`, `hWnd` should be `IntPtr`, `uCallbackMessage` and `uEdge` should be `UInt32`, and `lParam` should be `IntPtr`.

Comment: Also the `dwMessage` parameter in the `apiSHAppBarMessage` function should be `UInt32`, and the return value of the function should be `UIntPtr`.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, I'll have a read through it again and apply the changes you're suggesting.

Comment: Great! I suppose you'll update the answer when you've verified that the code still works? -- For reference, here's the documentation: [**`APPBARDATA` structure**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773184(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**Windows Data Types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: The data type conversion is actually pretty straightforward. Say you should convert the `cbSize` field (the data type `DWORD`): Lookup `DWORD` in the _Windows Data Types_ list and you'll see the declaration `typedef unsigned long DWORD;` (in C++ `long` = `int` = `int32`), thus you should have an _**unsigned**_ `Int32`, which is a `UInt32`. -- Any unknown and `*_PTR` data types are usually mapped to `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr`.

Comment: Exactly, I'm going to plug the code back into visual basic and run  it. Honestly, I'm pretty new to programming, so I didn't know most of the types you mentioned, so I need to look them up (and read the link you gave) and understand what they do and how they can improve on what they're replacing.

Comment: It seems the code I used as a reference is obsolete and only works on 32bit systems. I was getting bugs in x64 until I made the modifications you suggested and now it runs perfectly in x64. Thanks alot, Vincent. You're a life saver. I'll update the code in the answer.

Comment: I was using the integer return value apiSHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE, Nothing) to figure out if taskbar is Autohidden or not. What do I do with the UIntPtr type value that's now returned after I made my change? Do I simply use CInt(UIntPtr return value) so that I can plug it back into the rest of my code?

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm a bit short of time at the moment, but I can give you some more details about the data types later. -- `Do I simply use CInt(UIntPtr return value)` - Not quite. A `UIntPtr` can either be mapped to a `UInteger` or a `ULong` (depending on if it's a 32- or 64-bit system), so you should rather change the return type: `GetTaskBarAHState() As ULong` and then: `Return apiSHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETSTATE, Nothing).ToUInt64()`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give it a go.